# mongo - запрет на добавление новых полей при вставке и обновлении

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Как запретить создавать новые поля в документе, при insert и update? Столкнулся с такой проблемой, когда из nodejs кода обновлял в документе (mongodb) поле Name вместо name. В результате опечатки в документе было создано поле Name. Это не приемлемо. Я использовал родную библиотеку mongo для nodejs.

Comment: делайте проверку по тому полю, которое хотите заменить. `{name: {$exist: true}, {$set: {name: 'Petya'}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наложить такие "строгие" ограничения - воспользоваться способом @Shiki, либо средствами Mongoose.

Вообще для верси MongodDB 3.6 и выше можно использовать [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/).

Создаем правило для Schema Validation:

```
db.createCollection( "users", {
   validator: {
     $jsonSchema: {
       bsonType: "object",
       required: [ "name" ],
       properties: {
         name: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "must be a string and is required"
         }
       }
     }
   },
   validationAction: "error"
});
```

Правило `validationAction: "error"` запрещает вставку документов, не прошедших валидацию, а `validationAction: "warn"` - вставляет, но с предупреждением.

Попробуем вставить неконсистентный документ:

```
db.users.insert({"foo": "bar"});
```

Вернется ошибка:

```
WriteResult({
  "nInserted" : 0,
  "writeError" : {
    "code" : 121,
    "errmsg" : "Document failed validation"
  }
})
```

Валидный документ вставляется:

```
db.users.insert({"name": "Petya"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 });
```

> при использовании валидатора, нельзя будет вставить поле, которого нет в схеме?

можно:

```
db.users.insert({"name": "Petya", "Name": "Vasya"});
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 });
```

Comment: при использовании валидатора, нельзя будет вставить поле, которого нет в схеме?

Comment: @Дмытрык, можно, дополнил ответ.

Comment: Так в этом и проблема у вопрошающего. Из- за опечатки, фактически, вставляется новое поле

Answer (score 2):

Перед тем, как совать данные в insert||update делайте валидацию через [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi)