# Начало работы с MongoDB (управление базой)

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

Попал мне сайт (php) в котором используется MongoDB, честно говоря я никогда о ней не знал, то есть вопросы у меня сравнивая с mysql и ее веб интерфейсом phpmyadmin.

Интересуют вопросы:

Как управлять базой, есть ли какой либо веб интерфейс как phpmyadmin, или же Adminer для mysql.

Возможно ли удаленное управление, тогда как это можно реализовать, что за собой влечет?

На данный момент, интересуют только вопросы подключения к бд, с последующим ее управлением, так как ранее работал лишь с mysql.

Спасибо!

Comment: В гугл ходили и не нашли ничего?

Comment: Конечно, на данный момент вопрос лишь с интерфейсом управления), возможно конечно я писал не верный запрос по данному вопросу, или же упустил, что либо, что конечно вероятно

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/

Answer (score 3):

На тех кто до сих пор использует phpmyadmin пора уже косо смотреть :)

По поводу "управления" MongoDB - используйте бесплатный инструмент [Robo 3T](https://robomongo.org/)
Это не веб интерфейс (что крайне радует), а GUI.

Имейте в виду что MONGODB это нереляционная база данных. Таблицы называются коллекциями, а записи называются документами. В нет ней того что назывюат Join. Здесь не работает "сравнение" с привычными вам БД, это нечто другое. Здесь нет строгой структуры документа, в одну и ту же коллекцию вы можете записать какой угодно конфигурации документ. Здесь нет связей, по сему вы запросто можете удалить документ, который фигурирует ссылкой в другом документе и у вас "все поломается".

Само собой [документация](https://docs.mongodb.com/) в которой можно узнать подробнее любые аспекты работы БД, но, конечно, не скрою что для новичка это возможно покажется чуть сложным, странным и непонятным, однако если тот кто строил приложение понимал зачем он использует именно MongoDB, то вам повезло, а ежели потому "чтобы не как у большинства", то вероятно вам будет тяжеловато.

Comment: Что не так с `phpmyadmin` ?

Comment: @MoloF не вижу ни малейшей причины иметь вечную потенциальную дыру вместо того чтоб пользоваться вменяемыми GUI .

https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-784/Phpmyadmin.html

Не говоря об удобстве. Ресторить базы - то еще удовольствие.

Comment: Посоветуете GUI отличное от веб PhpMyAdmin ?

Comment: @MoloF прекраснейший инструмент (жаль платный) - Navicat https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql 

Ежели мы говорим про бесплатный - MysqlWorkBench https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: `В нет ней того что назывюат Join` - с какой-то версии уже есть. Называется [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). `в одну и ту же коллекцию вы можете записать какой угодно конфигурации документ` - в целом, да. Но можно сделать [Schema Validation](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1025302/287469). `запросто можете удалить документ, который фигурирует ссылкой` - да, но можно через mongoose сделать каскадное удаление https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348516/cascade-style-delete-in-mongoose

Comment: @TotalPusher спасибо, интересная новость. Но как я вижу это не join в классическом понимании.

Comment: @MoloF, @zalex `Что не так с phpmyadmin` - все в порядке, кто-то его использует, вот тут даже вендор рекомендуют использовать, правда админер https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql